# Is there ever a case when I should set my Swift CoreBluetooth CBCentralManager instance = nil?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In my iOS appl, after BLE connection and communication, I need to end the connection, and re-connect later same or another device.

I believe all I need to do is disconnect and stop scanning, and later re-start scanning, detect, and connect.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, though if it's the same device, you can save the CBPeripheral and reconnect to it. There's no need to rescan. You can also save the `periperhalID` and fetch a CBPeripheral for it using `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)`. There's no need to release your CBCentralManager. You can use it for the life of the program.