# iOS corebluetooth never reconnects

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I can connect my bluetooth device and interact without any problem, but when I try reconnect the problem occurs: iOS will never reconnect.

When I go far from the device, iOS is disconnected firing `didDisconnect`. I run `centralManager.connect` to reconnect without success. No peripheral event are fired.

Interestingly, I have the same problem when I call `centralManager.connect(identifierUUID)` from previously saved or registered bluetooth connection identifier. Nothing is fired.

I studied a lot of answers and I think I am coding the right way. Maybe, I need to run a background thread or something like that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your app in the foreground or suspended or terminated when the device comes back into range? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: The app is always in foreground. The next step would be to reconnect when in background

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show at least your `didDisconnect` code. Without seeing what you are doing it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Unluckily, the problem was the UUID identifier changed by IOS !!! So, it tries to reconnect to a lost device !!!

Comment: in your ```didDisconnect``` code, you're putting in the ```centralManager.connect()``` code at the end of it right? Are you using the ```identifierUUID```? Did you try to use the ```CBPeripheral``` instead?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73562092/14414215